# GXT: UiBinder new instance of a Widget

Tags: gxt, uibinder

I have a TextField form inside a window. Created with UiBinding. Next to the TextField is a button. I wanted to know if it was possible to create a new TextField widget when that button was pressed using UiBinder?

This is what I have:

Window class:

```
@UiField
TextField text;

@UiField
HorizontalPanel hPanel;
....
@UiHandler("addText")
public void onClick(SelectEvent event){
      hPanel.add(text);
}
```

My UiBinder file:

```
<gxt:Window ...(generic setup)...>
 <g:VerticalPanel>
  <gxt:FramedPanel>
   <container:VericalLayoutContainer>
    <container:child>
     <g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="hPanel">
      <form:FieldLabel text="Text">
       <form:Widget>
        <form:TextField ui:field="text"/>
       </form:Widget>
      </form:FieldLabel>
      <button:TextButton ui:field="addText"/>
     </g:HorizontalPanel>
    </container:child>
   </container:VericalLayoutContainer>
  </gxt:FramedPanel>
 </g:VerticalPanel>
</gxt:Window>
```

When I click the button it all it does is move the button from the right side of the text field to the left. I have more textfields in the window so I played around to see what it was really doing. It's taking that field and just moving it next to the button.

Is there a way I can create a new TextField underneath the original?

Answer (score 1):

Probably [LazyDomElement](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/LazyDomElement.html) will help you.